# reference_wrapper and implicit conversion

Tags: c++, c++11

Considering the following code:

```
int v = 12;
std::reference_wrapper<int> x(v);
std::reference_wrapper<const int> y(x);  // (1) This works
std::reference_wrapper<const int> z = x; // (2) This fails
```

if I understand correctly, (1) works because it only requires a single user-conversion, (2) fails because it involves two user-conversions in the conversion sequence:

```
std::reference_wrapper<int>::operator int& and
std::reference_wrapper<const int>::(const int&)
```

Thus,  `std::reference_wrapper<int>` is not *implicitly convertible* to `std::reference_wrapper<const int>` that breaks some of my code where I use `std::is_convertible` trait.

Is there any reason about this design involving the non-presence of a generic copy constructor:

```
template <typename Y>
reference_wrapper<T>::reference_wrapper(const reference_wrapper<Y>&)
```

(just like in `std::shared_ptr` for example) that would allow such an implicit conversion ?

Comment: Regardless of reasons, you should always unwrap `reference_wrapper`s if you are expecting them.

Comment: @Xeo This is quite the opposite, I'm passing a reference_wrapper of an UnaryFunction as a parameter of a template class that expects a UnaryFunction. More precisely:  
`typedef boost::transform_iterator<MyIterator, std::reference_wrapper<MyFunctor> > iterator`  
`typedef boost::transform_iterator<MyIterator, std::reference_wrapper<const MyFunctor> > const_iterator`  
and I would expect `iterator` to be _implicitely convertible_ to `const_iterator`.

Comment: In C++ different specializations of the same base type are unrelated, regardless of the relationship that the instantiating type have. `std::reference_wrapper<int>` is not more related to `std::reference_wrapper<const int>` than to `std::reference_wrapper<std::string>`. While you might *want* them to be convertible, I would not say that you should *expect* it to be.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit autoconversion between `std::reference_wrapper` and its underlying type (since it can be unsafe and confusing).

The correct syntax should be:

```
std::reference_wrapper<const int> z = x.get();
```

Comment: [Yes there is an implicit conversion from `std::reference_wrapper<T> -> T&`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get)

Comment: @Xeo: do we need it somewhere in this expression: ``std::reference_wrapper<const int> z = x;``?